# Rails - unable to update hour in datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a rails app where an "RFQ" has a datetime attribute.  The date is changed in a form but I want to set the hour to always be 15:00.

It works fine when I create the RFQ but if I edit it, it changes to 00:00:00

Create action:

```
 def create

   @rfq = Rfq.new(rfq_params)
    @rfq.owner = current_user.email
    @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfq.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rfq, notice: 'Rfq was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rfq }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rfq.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Update action

```
 def update
    @rfq.owner = current_user.email
    @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfq.update(rfq_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @rfq, notice: 'Rfq was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @rfq }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @rfq.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

After creation:

```
  Rfq Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "rfqs".* FROM "rfqs"  ORDER BY "rfqs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => Wed, 01 Jul 2015 15:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

After I edited

```
  Rfq Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "rfqs".* FROM "rfqs"  ORDER BY "rfqs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => Tue, 30 Jun 2015 00:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're changing the `due` attribute **before** updating it with values from the form.

You should instead do this:

```
def update
  @rfq.owner = current_user.email
  @rfq.attributes = rfq_params
  @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @rfq.save
      format.html { redirect_to @rfq, notice: 'Rfq was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @rfq }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @rfq.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, But why did i have to change @rfq.update(rfq_params) to if @rfq.save?  Why not always use .save instead of .update?

Comment: The main difference is the fact that we're assigning the values from the first first, *then* we're changing the due date, *then* we're saving. `update` is equivalent to assigning the params from the form and saving right away, which would overwrite the `due` you previously set a few lines before.